# Can't access files that were pushed to the Android device via ADB root from regular user

Tags: android, adb, file-permissions

I am having a problem accessing files pushed to my Android 12 tablet via ADB under a root account (see picture 1). I pushed a file to `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/Test`.

[image: (Picture 1)]

When doing a directory listing using a regular user in ADB I am unable to view the contents of the two files that were uploaded via ADB root user (See picture 2). Both '1.jpg' and '3.jpg' where uploaded using ADB root. The file '2.jpg' was uploaded using a the regular ADB user (i.e. ADB unrooted).

[image: (Picture 2)]

If I do a directory listing under the root shell user I can see all the files (See picture 3)

[image: (Picture 3)]

**Note:** that on '1.jpg' I changed the user & group (via 'chown shell:ext_data_rw 2.jpg') so that it matches '2.jpg'. So you would think '1.jpg' would be visible to a regular user since it has the same permissions, user, & group as '2.jpg' which is visible to regular user (See picture 3). Prior to running 'chown shell:ext_data_rw 2.jpg' it had the same user and group as '3.jpg' (i.e. root).

[image: (Picture 4)]

I used ADB to demonstrate this problem, but what I am really trying to solve is the same problem that occurs when I upload files via a sFTP server which running under a rooted SSH daemon. I figure most people don't have rooted SSH servers running on their Android device. I figured this would be closer to what they know. Not sure to do to make these files accessible to a regular user. What I'm trying to do is update files that are used by our Kotlin application (running under a regular user).

I think this is file permissions issue, but one of the other developers mentioned it may be a encryption issue (Encrypted Files System or File Based Encryption). He seemed to imply that the files where not visible between separate users. Not sure that makes sense to me as root user can see the file (2.jpg) uploaded by a regular user.

Any help would be appreciated.

What I tried:
Tried changing the owner of the file (via 'chown shell:ext_data_rw 2.jpg')
Tried changing the group the file belongs to (via 'chown shell:ext_data_rw 2.jpg')
Tried changing the permissions of the file (via 'chmod 777' etc.)

What I expected:
I want to view the contents of a file uploaded via ADB root from a regular ADB shell user

Comment: Please tell the full paths you pushed the files to.

Comment: To my knowledge the in `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/` each app as it's own directory and only this app specific directory can be accessed. So in your case only the app that has the packagename `Test` may access the pushed files.

Comment: @blackapps 
The directory I am pushing to is '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/Test' as mentioned above.

Comment: @Robert
You are correct that applications are not allowed to access other programs data as part of the scoped storage that was introduced in Android 10 (I think). However, you can always use ADB to bypass the scoped storage limitations by pushing a file using a regular user to an application folder. You can add / delete / update a file using ADB to any of the application folders. The difference is when I 'push' a file via ADB under root my program can't open it (see post above).

Comment: That is only a problem on Android 11+ devices.